# Best way to store variables in a function that will be used multiple times (c++)

Tags: c++, variables, structure

Main idea:

I wrote a piece of code for dijkstra's algorithm and I'm dandy. However, I need to call the function (from a header file) in other codes and stuff. But I need to store the variables only when the function is called (so once the function is called it will return variables but won't return variable from previous calls). And I need to reference these variables other codes/files.

How I'm storing variables:

a structure that contains two vector.

My question:

Would it be best to create a .h file to store a structure and just change the variables there or is there a way to call variable from another function in another file and use it without having to worry about memory issues and whatnot?

Also... how would I set up my .h file for this dijkstra algorithm if my my int main takes no arguments?......

-Edit-

```
typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
} STR;

STR Func()
{
 STR str;

str.a = 5;
str.b = 6;
return str;
}
```

Basic model of my code. But I need to reference the structure and it's variable in another file with another function. However I get undefined reference to 'main' error when compiling so I added an int main() that calls Func(). Suggestions?

-edit dos-

**Proposed fix**

.h should include:

```
struct_name dijkstra(input variables)
```

.cpp should include:

```
#include "dijkstra.h"

typedef struct{
blah...
}struct_name;

struct_name dijkstra{
struct_name retval;

function def...
return retval;
}
```

main.cpp should include:

```
#include "dijkstra.h"
#include "dijkstra.cpp"

int main(){

initialize variables... blah
struct_name return_struct = dijkstra(input variables);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How much memory are we talking about here? Seems like a non issue to me.

Comment: You mean storing algorithm-inner-process data in variables accesible globaly (i.e. in other functions)? And, you want data shared between calls, or data is restarted in each dijkstra's algoritm call?

Comment: Yes, and I need data to be restarted with each call.

Comment: Please refer to comments directed to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would pass in all the input data the algorithm needs as input parameters, and return all the useful output data the algorithm creats as a return type.  You could create a separate C++ struct or class if you need to bundle a few pieces of information together.

For data structures used internally by the algorithm - you would usually declare them only in the .cpp file, not the .h file.  So, the user will not have any access / visibility of the internals (which is useful if you want to change how it works later).

So, the header file should just have the function declaration - with input arguments and output return type.  All the algorithm code goes into the .cpp file, which includes the .h file.  The header file is the 'interface' and the cpp file is the 'implementation', which we try to keep separate.

EDIT : (summarizing useful points from subsequent discussion)

This tutorial shows how the 2 .cpp files and one .h file fit together.  Basically both .cpp files include the .h file.  The .h file includes the declarations (for both the function type and for the struct type) but not the function definition :

www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/

Since you are using g++, you can compile them into a single executable using :

g++ -o executable_name main.cpp dijkstra.cpp

Comment: this is the usual way of passing data to a function call - passing by value as function parameters.  If your input data is very large in size, then this approach won't make sense (you won't want to make a separate copy of the input data)

Comment: Thanks Graham. What you suggest is how I intend on going about this but there are still somethings I need to figure out:

so essentially I have a struct right? And the dijkstra function will take that and make changes and return it. That's all good.
But everytime I compile I get a undefined int main() error. So I threw in and int main(int argc, const char* argv) and call the dijkstra function within that. All good so far. But I'm afraid if I make a call to this through the header file I won't be able to reference the structure from another file.

Comment: Yup, completely agree with you. But in my dijkstra.cpp file, I get a undefined main error. I need an int main() of some kind.

Comment: let me give it a shot, thank you.

Also, how would I initialize the returned structure in another function within a different file?

Comment: Hey graham check out my 2nd edit. I think I'm making too many calls (a call in each file I think... getting a multiple definition error). I have a proposed fix in my edit.

Comment: Bear with me graham I'm almost there!

The typedef in dijkstra.cpp is not holding up in the header file. I.E. I have no idea what the return type in the header file should be when I call the function dijkstra.

Also, do I need to call/define the function in the int main()?

Comment: IT WORKED. THANK YOU! and yes, if you'd like to you may.

Comment: :) feel free to accept / upvote my answer if it was useful :)

Comment: I'm going to delete all my comments.  Suggest you do the same in a bit...otherwise it will look like you are talking to yourself ;)